# Reset a network connection by name?

Tags: windows-10, networking, script

[image]

I quite often need to reset "Ethernet" connection as shown above. Currently I disable then enable it from the control panel but I wonder if I can create a script that I can simply double-click from my desktop or whatever?

My preference would be a batch file simply as I'm most familiar, but I would imagine this is perhaps more suited to Powershell?

Comment: You normally should not need to do this. Can you explain why you do this? What it fixes? We might be able to help you with the underlying cause so you don't need to reset the adapter in the first place.

Comment: It's an ongoing complex virtualisation issue @LPChip, the root cause I've been chasing with the vendor for over a year! But this is a standalone question I would still like to know an answer to.

Answer (score 3):

Two methods to reset (disable & enable) a network adapter.

**Using wmic**

```
wmic nic get name, index                                (to find the index - 2)
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=2 call disable
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=2 call enable
```

**Using netsh**

```
netsh interface show interface                          (to find the name - Ethernet 2)
netsh interface set interface "Ethernet 2" disable
netsh interface set interface "Ethernet 2" enable
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also try to run the following command in PowerShell:

Run **Get-Netadapter** to show all the network adapter of your device.

Then select the adapter you need disable, and please run **Disable-Netadapter -Name "xxxxxx"**

For more details, please refer to the following article:

[Disable-NetAdapter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/disable-netadapter?view=win10-ps)